# Phase portrait of n-dimensional state-space system

Tags: differential-equations, dynamic, differential-geometry

It is usually not difficult to study the state space for n = 2,3 variable states.
What if these variables are more than 3, for example 4,5 or 6?
There is a rule according to which the dynamic features of the system can be estimated by constructing the C (n, 2) phase planes of combinations of variables of the state space.

> ${C_{{2}}}^{n}=1/2\,{\frac {n}{ \left( n-2 \right) !}}$

This approach is presented in the article, the link to which I attached to the message.
1. How, using Mathematica, to build phase portraits for an n-dimensional state space if it is non-autonomous (time-varying sinusoidal signals are included in the system)?
2. Using the Pfaff equations, one can exclude time from consideration and obtain paths in the state space (by integrating the 1-form). How to evaluate the closedness of a 1-form and determine the linear dependence/independence of 1-forms for the corresponding pair of Pfaff equations and differentiate externally using Mathematica?
A system with 4 variables in the state space is shown below.

$\left\{ {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}x \left( t \right) =v \left( t 
 \right) +\sin \left( t \right)  \right\}$

$\left\{ {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}y \left( t \right) =-6\,x \left( t 
\right) -y \left( t \right) -3\, \left( z \left( t \right)  \right) ^
 {2}+\sin \left( 2\,t \right)  \right\} $

$\left\{ {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}z \left( t \right) =-1\,x \left( t 
\right) -y \left( t \right) -8\, \left( z \left( t \right)  \right) ^
 {2}+\sin \left( 3\,t \right)  \right\} $

$\left\{ {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}v \left( t \right) =-4\,x \left( t 
\right) -y \left( t \right) -5\, \left( z \left( t \right)  \right) ^
 {2}+\sin \left( 8\,t \right)  \right\} $

[On the n-Dimensional Phase Portraits](https://www.mdpi.com/2076-3417/9/5/872/pdf)

Comment: What do all those `>`'s mean?

Comment: Sorry, this occurred while transferring the formula from Maple. I mistreat this editor, so i tried to edit it as i could. In these symbols > there is no sense.